# PHPDoc can't see define in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

In one file I am creating a constant:

```
/**
 * Relative path to author photo used by default.
 * Used when author photo is not loaded.
 * 
 * @const DEFAULT_AVATAR_PATH
 */
define('DEFAULT_AVATAR_PATH', '/images/authors/def_author.png');
```

After that I am trying to use this constant in PHPDoc in another php file:

```
/**
 * Relative path to author photo.
 * If there is no photo loaded it contains default author image path ({@see DEFAULT_AVATAR_PATH}).
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $photo_url;
```

So I can see blue text in my PHPStorm:

[image]

However I can't click on it. It shows nothing!

How to fix it?

Comment: There're two bugs in PhpStorm actually. The first one is that inline `@see` tag is not supported ([WI-26923](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-26923)). The second one is about constants inside `@see` tag ([WI-34937](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-34937)). If you'd like them to be fixed, please vote for the mentioned issues.